# What am I doing wrong? (Razor Syntax & WebSecurity)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, razor, webmatrix

I am implementing the WebSecurity feature with WebMatrix, but it produces errors on my page!

The error makes no sense to me:

Code:

```
  <div class="signInOrRegister">

    @if(WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        <h1>@WebSecurity.CurrentUserName</h1>
        <p>You may view your Account Options by clicking <a href="#" class="ShowAccountToolbarAndMenu">View Account Options</a>
    }
    else
    {
        <h1>Sign In</h1>
        <p class="signInSummary">Already a Customer? Sign In here.</p>
        <div class="smallVerticalSpace"> </div>
        <form action="@Request.ServerVariables["URL"]" method="post">
          <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" class="formTable">
            <tr>
              <td class="leftTD">
                <label for="email" class="UsernameLabel">E-mail Address:</label><br />
                <!--@Html.TextBox("Email", null, new { @class="email" })-->
              </td>
              <td class="rightTD">
                <label for="password" class="customerIdLabel">Password:</label><br />
                <!--@Html.Password("Password", null, new { @class="password"})-->
              </td>
              <td class="LastTD">
                <label for="rememberMe" class="rememberMeLabel">Remember me?</label><br />
                @Html.CheckBox("rememberMe")

                <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Sign In" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </form>
    }

  </div>
```

The error:

```
Parser Error 
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: The if block is missing a closing "}" character.  Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as markup.


Source Error: 


Line 42:       <div class="signInOrRegister">
Line 43:         
Line 44:         @if(WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated)
Line 45:         {
Line 46:             <h1>@WebSecurity.CurrentUserName</h1>


Source File: /_SiteLayout.cshtml    Line: 44 


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1
```

So, after reading the error, I've made sure nothing's been treated as markup. I've done this by commenting-out the @Html.TextBox("Email", new etc) controls. But it still produces this same error. What's going on? I don't see the problem here. The rest of the page is just static HTML, and worked fine before I put the WebSecurity stuff in.

Any help is appreciated

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to close your paragraph `<p>` wihtin your if-statement (Line 47)! This could be the cause of the error.

Comment: Oh my... I'm such a dumb-ass. I've been looking all over the place and did not see that. Thank you!